# JTA Callbacks in Spring

Tags: spring, unit-testing, transactions, junit, jta

Is it possible to register some kind of callback with a JTA transaction in a Spring application?

I've got some mock services that are standing in for remote services that belong to another application that's normally accessed using Spring's `HttpInvoker`. These mock services model data in-memory in a trivial fashion using `Map`s and the like.

The Unit tests don't necessarily know which of these services might get used; the service the test case is targetting might use them behind the scenes.

The unit tests are transactional, and Spring's `SpringJUnit4ClassRunner` will rollback the transaction after each test, meaning that the state fo our unit test database is preserved between tests.

How can I rollback the state of this custom in-memory service implementation? If there was a way of finding out if there's a transaction currently going on, then I was hoping there'd be a way of registering a callback with the `TransactionManager` to be executed before the transaction is completed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it's a good idea to clean up test mock in such an implicit way - tests usually perform cleanup explicitly.

However, if you really want, take a look at [`TransactionSynchronizationManager.registerSynchronization()`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/support/TransactionSynchronizationManager.html).

Comment: I have wrote a blog post about transaction synchronization in Spring and how to easily register after commit callbacks http://azagorneanu.blogspot.com/2013/06/transaction-synchronization-callbacks.html